# JSF - JAVA Find all Forms in View

Tags: java, forms, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a webbpage designed with primefaces layout. There are different layout units and in each layout unit, here is a form called "form".  depends on the page. Now I want to reload only these forms and not the whole page. How do I find only the forms with the pattern "form" in the id ?

I tried to use:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot()
            .getChildren()
```

But there I only get the components of this layout unit / form and not from the whole page.

Every help is more than welcome.

(Technologies: JSF 2.2, Tomcat 7, Primefaces 4.0)

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a common layout under the forms layouts with an`id`. Then try to invoke the appropriate method of viewroot to find element by `id` - it will be this common layout. Next step, iterations over child elements to find your forms. You know forms is a second level child for common layout. Iterate over common layout child of childs.